# Hive DISTINCT() for all columns?

Tags: sql, hive

I wanted clarification as to how DISTINCT works, using a toy example below. Suppose you had a table like so, with 2 columns and only 2 rows of data:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1;

colA   colB
A      B
A      C
```

Suppose I ran a SELECT DISTINCT query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT colA, colB 
FROM table1;
```

Which of the following results would be returned for the query above?

Outcome possibility 1:

```
A      B
A      C
```

The thinking for this possibility is that while the values are not distinct on `colA`, the entire returned row is unique, or distinct, when both columns are considered. I'm uncertain because of the effect of the comma between `colA` and `colB` in `SELECT DISTINCT colA, colB` and whether it serves to limit the `DISTINCT` to `colA`.

Outcome possibility 2:

```
A      B
```

Outcome possibility 3:

```
A      C
```

Comment: Possibility 1.  ***Distinct applies to ALL columns selected.***  If you just selected colA then you'd get 1 record result A: if you just selected distict column B then you'd get B, and C.  If you had a 3rd record A,B, then you'd still only get two records when selecting distinct colb as the 3rd record would be a duplicate of the first. and you'd only get 2 records when using distinct colA, ColB as the 3rd record is again an exact duplicate of record 1.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps this will help.  This query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT colA, colB 
FROM table1;
```

is functionally equivalent to:

```
SELECT colA, colB 
FROM table1
GROUP BY colA, colB;
```

It is going to return all pairs of `colA`/`colB` that appear in the data.

Comment: As an aside, between both of those functionally equivalent solutions, is one computationally more efficient than the other? Not sure if there is a simple answer or a more nuanced one. I am interested because I deal with petabytes of data.

Comment: @user2205916 . . . That depends on the database, but the performance should be pretty similar.

Comment: This is a nice trick that sped up my query.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The DISTINCT apply on complete row.

```
A      B
A      C
```

The above two rows a different so the result will be like Outcome possibility 1
i.e.

```
A   B
A   C
```